# How much disk space is available to an application on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, diskspace

I am planning to store videos inside my app's Documents folder, so I need to know how much memory is available to an application. Is there is any limit on how much can I put inside my application's Documents folder? Would that affect performance or reduce disk space available to my application for running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, your only *storage* limit is the device's memory. [According to Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager#comment-5924) the only limit is 2GB per file. I can't verify offhand, but Ray usually knows what he is talking about. I'd trust that.